# What is this thing on the mint plant leaves?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, fungus

I have a pepper mint plant that I grow using growth light in a windowsill. Recently there has ben some wierd thing on the leaves that I don't know what is. Is this an infection? Is it fungii? Is it safe for eating? I use the mint plant in home made cocktails and wonder if this is safe and still useable. Here are some pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also as a side note: If I need to take countermeasures, any idea how I would do that? Do I need to throw away the plant entirely?

Please help me using the appropriate tags, if I have used the wrong ones.